# Remove SharePoint App (not only instances)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

Hi I'm wondering if I can remove an app entirely from SharePoint 2013. What I'm looking for is not the removal of an already added app instance, rather I want to disallow users to add this specific app to any of the sites (or hide the app).

On TechNet I just found some information about locating all instances and the removal of them ([here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161233.aspx)), which does not prevent users from re-adding this app.

Is there some kind of "App Gallery" where I can administer the apps (similar to the "Web Part Gallery" or "List Template Gallery") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You must be a SharePoint admin to be able to do this. You can disable apps from the SharePoint admin center. Go to SharePoint admin center > apps. You have options such as App Catalog, Purchase Apps, Manage Licenses, Configure Store Settings, Monitor Apps and App permissions.